# All Time Zone Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, timezone, global

Does anyone have the All Global Timezone data in a database. If anyone have then please help me providing with the same. I couldn't find while searching on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux distributions have this as a package called tzdata or zoneinfo. If you are using Python, try pytz: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Wander but I am using PHP and MySQL and I need the data in database. Not the setting.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has built-in time zone support, and its time zone tables are accessible both through functions like `CONVERT_TZ()` to convert datetime values from one time zone to another, or, once the tables are populated by the script provided with the server software, **you query access the data in the time zone tables directly, as well, whether or not you need MySQL's time zone functions**.  The are in the "mysql" system database, but they are empty by default, since they are intended to be populated from your operating system's time zone information, if it exists, or there's a common database you can download from the MySQL web site if the system doesn't have such functiinality.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: @Soumya - If you're specifically looking for MYSQL time zone support, this is the correct answer.  Read the first link carefully for installation instructions.  You don't want to be managing your own data yourself.  If you're looking for PHP time zone support, that's [built-in](http://ca3.php.net/timezones), and the data is updated [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb)

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks... I may not have explained it as clearly as I intended to, but the MySQL time zone tables that MySQL uses to implement its time zone functionality seem to me to address the "all global time zone data in a database" aspect of the question, which is the primary reason I posted the answer (since MySQL was mentioned, anyway) -- the time zone information used by the internal time zone functions is also exposed and directly queriable in tables, even if there's not a desire to use the actual time zone functions of MySQL.

Comment: @Soumya - Please recognize that both MySQL and PHP, along with countless others, all use the [IANA/Olson Time Zone Database](http://iana.org/time-zones).  See also [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).